# Function works once, not the second time around

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my program I start with this...

```
def start():
    acu.cont
    acu.php
    input('Welcome... ( Press Enter )')
    acga.Game.game()
start()
```

This works fine and start the game normally the first time around. When I finish the game I have this..

```
again = '1'
    print('Play again? ( 1 for yes, 2 for no )')
    again = input()
    while again == '1':
        import Start
        Start.start()
    else:
        print('adios')
        raise SystemExit
```

After choosing to play again the game displays the welcome message like normal, but pressing enter does nothing. I'm left in limbo.

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks

Comment: There is no `while ..  else`. You are infinitely importing `Start`

Comment: Since you do not show the code of `acga.Game.game()` I cannot tell you exactly why the game does not start again. But `while again == '1':` surely is not what you want, because it will issue infinite calls to `Start.start()`. Try `if again == '1':` instead.

Comment: @handle: while... else is a perfectly valid construct in Python. (It might not be correct here, granted...)

Comment: Yes `while ... else` is valid, but it always executes the `else` unless there is a `break`

Comment: Hi all, OP here... I've changed the while to if. It now loads game()... the exits the game. I will explore game() to try and figure this out. Thanks for all the help guys. If... when I figure it out I will update my post.

Comment: I stand corrected: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

Comment: Why do you have an `import` statement in a loop? Python will not  attempt to import a module that it has already imported unless you explicitly tell it to reload the module, and even then reloading the module may not do exactly what happens on the initial import of the module. You should put all `import` statements at the top of the module unless you have a **very** good reason to put them elsewhere.

Comment: handle, thanks for the advice. I was fighting an import loop. Having the import mid-code ended up not helping, so I've moved it back to the top. As to my original problem... I did get it to restart the game, but it wasn't correctly resetting some of my vars, so I scrapped the notion of having a reset for now. I'll come back to it when the game is more fleshed out and I have more skill. -Thanks for the advice all

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the `while` in

```
while again == '1':
```

to `if`.

Comment: This answer seems to be correct doesn't it? Why was it down-voted so massively?